# Cannot Connect Other Computers to Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, networking, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am able to register nodes to the hub when I'm working on just one computer, but when I try to connect a node that is running on another computer I get a timeout or a message saying the hub must be down or not responding. I have no idea how to solve this.

After starting the hub I get the message: Nodes should register to http:192.168...:4444/grid register.

A tutorial said that

> "you can check if Machine B can access the hub's web interface by launching a browser there and going to where "iporhostnameofmachineA" should be the IP address or the hostname of the machine where the hub is running. Since Machine A's IP address is 192.168.1.3, then on the browser on Machine B you should type >http://192.168.1.3:4444/grid/console."

But chrome is giving me a "This site can't be reached error". This must be an issue with my network configuration, but I do not how what I should do to fix it.

Comment: First check whether machines are in LAN and can talk to each other, you can use ping command for that

Comment: I successfully just pinged the hub computer by entering the IP address without the port number @4M01

Comment: What command you are using to register the node from remote machine?

Comment: Please specify what the operating systems are of the selenium grid and node machines.

Comment: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig %userprofile%\git\Selenium\src\ex13\chrome_node.json -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=%userprofile%\.m2\repository\webdriver\chromedriver\win32\2.22\chromedriver.exe   .... the json file has all of the actual settings which work on one machine,   and all machines in the grid are windows 7

Comment: I have faced the same issue. And yes kyleM is right. It was a firewall issue. I have disabled it for 5min (As i was using kaspersky antivirus it had that option) and tried the whole process again. And it wokred. It gave me a popup saying that windows firewall has blocked some JAVA something like that. And it had an option "Allow access" i have clicked on that and after that i have enabled the firewall again. And this time it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using the command `'telnet 192.168.1.3 4444'` from your Selenium node and see if it connects. On the machine running the hub, (so 192.168.1.3) run `'netstat -antp | grep 4444'` (assuming it's a linux machine) and make sure you see an entry showing that the port is being listened on. If it's a windows machine you can still use netstat but not grep I think. Once you confirm that the hub is indeed listening on port 4444, and you can ping 192.168.1.3, but cannot telnet to port 4444, you have basically determined that there is a firewall issue. Then you would need to look into the firewalls on both machines, and any firewalls between them.

Comment: Also, side note: this question is better for serverfault.com since it seems to be a networking question not a Selenium one.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @KyleM I'll have IT try these commands out on Monday as I do not have admin rights on this computer.

Comment: @atg I do not think telnet requires admin rights to use, although if it is not enabled, it might require admin rights to install. But yeah, it sounds like you are blocked by a firewall. Good luck

Comment: I was able to connect nodes to the hub only after IT disabled the firewall. So it is a firewall issue, but we are still trying to figure out the exact settings so we can turn it back on and not block request. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @atg No problem, if this solved your question then, please mark as solved.